# F# error array slicing when using 4.3.1 fsharp core version

Tags: f#

I get the error when build my project with latest fharp core(4.3.1) for .Net 4.0.

> Error 20  The value, constructor, namespace or type
>   'GetArraySlice2DFixed1' is not
>   defined   C:\dev\dev\PrimitiveTemplatesApp\SvgPreprocess\BinaryParsers.fs 113 36  SvgPreprocess

Code:

```
let width, height = arr.[0,*].Length, arr.[*,0].Length
```

I want to use fharp 4.3.1 for using some libraries but also I need to use .Net 4.0 - can't update on .Net 4.5+ now for backward compatibility reason. Is there solution other than not use array slicing? Thanks.

Comment: Why if FSharp.Core 4.3.1 necessary for your libraries? It is generally backwards compatible, so you can use a higher version with a library that expects a lower one.

Comment: What OS are you on? I am seeing there being some OS related issues to this https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues/116

Comment: @JosephStevens thanks. I use Windows. If this is error in fsharp I should to use older fsharp version(4.3.0) with .Net 4.0?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin 4.3.1 required by some Nuget dependecies. 4.3.1 is last available version for using with .Net 4.0 as I know, isn't it?